# Как перевести диапазоны IP адресов в список адресов?

Tags: c++, ip, библиотеки, tcp-ip

Есть около сотни диапазонов IP адресов. В формате:

```
1.3.1.3-250.255.250.250
```

Нужно из каждого получить список IP. Подскажите есть ли какие то библиотеки C/C++ для этого или в крайнем случае интернет сервисы?

Comment: Что-то странные какие-то диапазоны... Справа точно IP, а не (испорченная) маска? Что до библиотек - то тут нет абсолютно ничего сложного, это же просто 4 байта... Сложнее разбираться с масками подсетей, специальными адресами и т.п....

Comment: @Harry Это просто пример формата. Диапазоны там конечно другие.

Comment: Нормальный IP. Диковатый, конечно, из зарезервированного диапазона, но вполне себе легитимный.

Comment: @Akina Да просто, как вы понимаете, скажем, 1.3.1.3 с маской 255.255.255.252 - это тоже диапазон ip-адресов, просто считается он совершенно иначе...

Comment: @Harry. Нет, "адрес плюс маска" - это или адрес, или подсеть (или, с учётом того, что на классы все забили уже давно и прочно - то просто сеть). Для пары 1.3.1.3/255.255.255.252 - это однозначно адрес, потому как для сети addr AND (NOT mask) == 0. А вот "от адреса до адреса" - это как раз диапазон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, обратите внимание на обычные системные сокеты. В Windows - на winsock2.h, например.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;

char * start = "1.3.1.3";
char * stop  = "1.3.2.2";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned long begin = ntohl(inet_addr(start));
    unsigned long end   = ntohl(inet_addr(stop));
    cout << hex << begin << endl;
    cout << hex << end << endl;
    for(;begin < end; ++begin)
    {
        in_addr a;
        a.s_addr = ntohl(begin);
        cout << inet_ntoa(a) << endl;
    }
}

#pragma comment(lib,"wsock32.lib")
```

Думаю, без проблем найдете и в GCC. Кажется, в , но тут я не уверен, с GCC не работаю, в общем-то.

Но еще раз должен напомнить о том, что ip-адреса - это не совсем просто 4-байтные числа.

Answer (score 1):

Формируем целочисленный адрес, путём склеивания сегментов адреса, и проходим по нему циклом:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint32_t a0 = 100;
    uint32_t b0 = 150;
    uint32_t c0 = 0;
    uint32_t d0 = 200;

    uint32_t a1 = 105;
    uint32_t b1 = 150;
    uint32_t c1 = 3;
    uint32_t d1 = 210;

    uint32_t s = (((((a0 << 8) | b0) << 8) | c0) << 8) | d0;
    uint32_t e = (((((a1 << 8) | b1) << 8) | c1) << 8) | d1;

    for (uint32_t addr = s; addr <= e; ++addr)
    {
        int a = addr >> 24;
        int b = (addr >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int c = (addr >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int d = addr & 0xFF;
        std::cout << a << "." << b << "." << c << "." << d << "\n";
    }
}
```

Библиотека готова!

Comment: Увы, например, 100.150.1.150 выведен не будет. У вас в каждом октете получается свой диапазон. А если вывести надо, скажем, 100.110.120.130 - 100.110.121.100? Что будет выведено?

Comment: @Harry fixed!!!